# C4 and Creatine together

Tags: energy, creatine

I have used C4 before, with strong effect I might add, never really used creatine. I was wondering since C4 already has some creatine in it, is it ok to use them at the same time and will it possibly change the effects of each other.

Comment: What is C4 in this context? How does this relate to Physical fitness?

Comment: @FredrikD C4 is a pre-workout supplement

Comment: was thinking about doing the same thing since c4 is so light on creatine bbut definitely gives a good preworkout boost. did u notice any results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used C4 quite a bit along side with Creatine as well. Depending on your creatine, C4 won't be giving you that much creatine (I believe it was 1g per scoop). Some people claimed creatine needed a "loading phase" but that hasn't been proven.

In fact, the "loading phase" was popularized by companies who wanted to sell more of their product. They would suggest a loading phase and the consumer would be using more during the first weeks (without any added results).

---

Creatine is a natural amino acid present in the body of humans and animals. The human body has 100-115 grams of creatine in the form of creatine phosphate. No negative side effects have been noted in the research with the recommended levels of supplementation.

Depending on your weight, here are the [creatine](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/dimaggio2.htm) intakes per day:

- Less than or equal to 140lbs = 5-6grams per day is maintenance
- 141lbs to 168lbs = 6-7.5 grams per day is maintenance
- 169lbs to 199lbs = 8 grams per day is maintenance
- 200lbs to 242lbs = 8-10 grams per day is maintenance
- 242lb+ = 10-12 grams per day

*Gotten from bodybuilding.com*

You'll be fine if you use creatine and C4 together. Just drink water due to the added creatine levels. When I cycle on creatine I use about 5g per day even if I'm 170lbs.

P.S: If you liked C4, you might love Craze. My new pre-workout.

Comment: What made u switch to craze

Comment: @aaronman I wanted to try something new. I had been hearing a lot about Craze and I love it. Insane focus on it - but not the best taste (especially not compared to C4)

Comment: @Alex i was wondering, what is really affect of creatine, and what happens if to overtake it, like at my age itt should be 8 grams but, cellucor is 11g of scoop.

Comment: @Nofel 11g won't be harmful. Click here for more information: http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/6-side-effects-of-creatine-myths-debunked.html

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what C4 you are talking about, but if it includes creatine, the effect of adding more creatine, will be the same as if you just took lots of creatine.

Check how much creatine is in C4, then add creatine **up to a max of 5g per day**. [More than that may cause minor negative effects](http://examine.com/supplements/Creatine/), but is mostly a waste of money. Consuming more than 5g a day of creatine has no research-backed positive benefits.

Comment: C4 is a preworkout supplement for energy

Answer (score 0):

C4 uses 1g creatine nitrate though.  Not the same as mono.  Technically most people say 1g of creatine nitrate is equal to 5g of mono.  Take it for what it is and go from there.